# Passing an extend as a mixin argument in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create a "master" text mixin but have some trouble with it.

Font family extend

```
@mixin isMainFont($weight, $style) {
    font-family: $main;
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;
}
%mainRegular {
    @include isMainFont(400,normal)
}
```

Font-size mixin

```
@mixin fontSize($sizeValue) {
  font-size: $sizeValue / 10 + rem;
}
```

Some color variable

```
$mainTxtColor: #000000;
```

Now I can write my master mixin

```
@mixin isTxt ($family, $size, $color) {
    @extend $family;
    @include fontSize($size);
    color: $color;
}
```

After all this is done, I can start styling real dom elements. Let's have an example

```
.articleTitle {
    @include isTxt(mainExtraBold, 22, $mainTxtColor)
}
```

But SASS doesn't accept that line

```
@extend $family
```

Seems I can't extend a mixin parameter. Or have I missed something ?

Comment: Why are trying to extend an argument? How does that even make sense?

Comment: Well the argument has to be an existing extend class of course